# Problems with logging in/out standart django user using class-based views

Tags: python, django, django-1.6

I am trying to create simple application that allows just login existing user and logout if logged in.

views.py

```
from django.views.generic.edit  import FormView
from django.views.generic       import DetailView

from django.contrib.auth        import logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms  import AuthenticationForm

from django.core.urlresolvers   import reverse_lazy

from django.http                import HttpResponseRedirect


class UserDetailView( DetailView ):
    model = User
    template_name = "main/user_detail.html"

class UserLoginView( FormView ):
    form_class = AuthenticationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("UserDetails")
    template_name = "main/user_form.html"

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls   import patterns, include, url

from main               import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',),
    url( r'users/(?P<pk>\d+)/', views.UserDetailView.as_view(), name="UserDetails"),
    url( r"logout/", views.logout_view, name="UserLogOut" ),
    url( r"login/", views.UserLoginView.as_view(), name="UserLogIn" ),
)
```

user_form.html

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<a href="{% url 'Main:UserLogOut' %}">Logout</a>
{{ user.username }}
{% else %}

<form method='post'> {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

{% endif %}

I don't know why, but server returns this error

```
Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://0.0.0.0:9000/login/
Django Version:     1.6.5
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    

Reverse for 'UserDetails' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

What's wrong?

---

**UPD**
I've tried this dirty hack `success_url = reverse_lazy("Main:UserDetails", kwargs={ 'pk':1 } )` just to check that it's working. I've also added

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
Hooray!
{% else %}
What the hell???
{% endif %}
```

to the user_detail.html and for some reason got **What the hell???** instead of **Hooray!**
Why authentication form doesn't actually authenticates user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in this statement

```
success_url = reverse_lazy("UserDetails")
```

You need to provide user pk to reverse_lazy args, because URL is in form "users/user_id/".
So it's impossible to find out correct success URL.

Comment: Yo can override `get_success_url` method in your `UserLoginView` where you will provide `pk` parameter to reverse_lazy function. You can take `pk` from your form instance.

It seems it would be even better to override `form_valid(form)` method because you have form instance passed into the method.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_valid

Answer (score 0):

In this line in your urlconf

```
url( r'users/(?P<pk>\d+)/', views.UserDetailView.as_view(), name="UserDetails"),
```

you are defining the url for UserDetails as 'something/users/**pk**'. But then you are not supplying a pk argument to that url. That's why your error says that the reverse was not found, because it tries to find a pattern which has no arguments.

There are several ways to fix your error, but I think the best solution would be to make the **pk** argument optional, like this:

```
url( r'users(?:/(?P<pk>\d+))?/', views.UserDetailView.as_view(), name="UserDetails"),
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried it. Still getting the same error. Maybe something wrong in the template or `reverse_lazy` call?

Comment: Ah, it seems DetailView *needs* a pk argument, and you can not make it optional. But you can (and MUST) pass it in your reverse call. Something like this `reverse_lazy('UserDetails', kwargs={'pk': YOUR_PK})`

Comment: Done it. There is no more errors but after redirection user is not authenticated.

Comment: That is because in your code there is no **login**. I mean something like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login)

Comment: I thought AuthenticationForm does that.

Comment: Sorry, but I've never used AuthenticationForm, so I don't really know if it does what you want it to. I still think that the form only does the authentication part, and that you should call **login** yourself, but I can't say it for sure. And I have nowhere to test it right now ...